# devise and authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I've been trying all day to get a way to authenticate via a simple get.

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def signin
    warden.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    render :json => current_user.to_json
  end
end
```

When I hit this with something like http://localhost:3000/api/signin?email=theemailaddress&password=thepassword

I get the message: "Invalid strategy theemailaddress", here is the stack:

```
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/proxy.rb:323:in `_fetch_strategy'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/proxy.rb:307:in `block in _run_strategies_for'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/proxy.rb:306:in `each'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/proxy.rb:306:in `_run_strategies_for'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/proxy.rb:279:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/proxy.rb:90:in `authenticate'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
```

What do I need to get something like this going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom warden strategy and check the request headers. Look at what [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166268/519559).

Comment: In addition to doing that I had to specify the strategy when calling into warden. "warden.authenticate!(:loginstrategy)"

Comment: It's also useful to note that once you get the user you can call user.validate_password?(password)

Comment: That's true. In my case I did not use passwords, the username was all I needed to create/fetch an account because the proxy handled all the pre-authentication.